# Avoid creating temporary tables / Make a "local left join" PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have these 3 queries, and I have to make them a lot of times (one for each day of a given month). It takes a lot of time to do it.

```
$sqldia = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE today AS (SELECT * FROM booking WHERE day = ".$weekday.")";
$sqldia2 = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE taken AS (SELECT * FROM b_users WHERE date = '".$date."')";
$sqldia3 = "SELECT A.from, A.to FROM today A LEFT JOIN turnostomados B ON A.from = B.to WHERE B.confirmed IS NULL";
```

The queries are okay, the code works as expected but it's really slow. This needs to be a fast query and not consume much resources because it can be used a lot of times in a short period of time.

How do I improve this?
Is there any way to make a "local left join" in PHP?

Comment: How are you using the `taken` temp table?  The 3rd query can be rewritten with a `join` between `booking` and `turnostomados` adding the appropriate `where` criteria -- no need for the 1st temp table (and presumably the second)...

Comment: Please add the PHP code which calls these statements for different dates. Chances are that *all* of that can be replaced with one SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you don't need temporary tables (especially 2nd one, as its not used at all):

```
SELECT
A.from, A.to
FROM booking as A
LEFT JOIN
turnostomados as B
ON (A.from = B.to)
WHERE A.day = ".$weekday."
AND B.confirmed IS NULL
```

then, run [`explain extended`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-extended.html) to find out execution plan and add appropriate indexes to these two tables

probably you will need index on bookings `(day, from, to)`

Answer (score 0):

Asumming that by `turnostomados` you meant `taken` and you just forgot to translate it... then you only need one query:

```
$sql = "SELECT A.from, A.to FROM booking A LEFT JOIN b_users B ON A.from = B.to
WHERE B.confirmed IS NULL AND A.day = ".$weekday." AND B.date = '".$date."'"
```

Also, make sure that `$weekday` and `$date` are properly sanitized as otherwise you are vulnerable to SQL injection.